# to merge lists in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have the following python code:

```
import subprocess

def disk():
for i in ('/tmp' , '/usr/mware' , '/var' , '/var/mware'):
    df1 = subprocess.Popen(['df','-h', i], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split()
    df1.remove("on")
    print df1

disk()
```

I am getting the following output:

```
['Filesystem', 'Size', 'Used', 'Avail', 'Use%', 'Mounted', '/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmplv', '2.0G', '39M', '2.0G', '2%', '/tmp']
['Filesystem', 'Size', 'Used', 'Avail', 'Use%', 'Mounted', '/dev/mapper/appvg-usrmwarelv', '20G', '33M', '20G', '1%', '/usr/mware']
['Filesystem', 'Size', 'Used', 'Avail', 'Use%', 'Mounted', '/dev/mapper/rootvg-varlv', '10G', '3.8G', '6.3G', '38%', '/var']
['Filesystem', 'Size', 'Used', 'Avail', 'Use%', 'Mounted', '/dev/mapper/appvg-varmwarelv', '20G', '33M', '20G', '1%', '/var/mware']
```

I want to merge these lists and remove duplicates.

Comment: And what is an expecting result? You want merge lists or their elements?

Comment: df1 is your output list ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you spawn separate processes for every filesystem to check, while `df` is able to check all of them in one run?

```
df1 = subprocess.Popen(['df','-h', '/tmp' , '/usr/mware' , '/var' , '/var/mware'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split()
```

Comment: Although that's a good remark, this is not the point of the question. You should post this as a comment instead.

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me, i edited the code like:
`import subprocess

def disk():
    df = []
    for i in ('/tmp' , '/usr/mware' , '/var' , '/var/mware'):
        df1 = subprocess.Popen(['df','-h', '/tmp' , '/usr/mware' , '/var' , '/var/mware'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split()
    df1.remove("on")
    print df1


disk()`

Answer (score 1):

merging lists is so simple.

```
a= ['Filesystem', 'Size', 'Used', 'Avail', 'Use%', 'Mounted', '/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmplv', '2.0G', '39M', '2.0G', '2%', '/tmp']
b= ['Filesystem', 'Size', 'Used', 'Avail', 'Use%', 'Mounted', '/dev/mapper/appvg-usrmwarelv', '20G', '33M', '20G', '1%', '/usr/mware']
c= ['Filesystem', 'Size', 'Used', 'Avail', 'Use%', 'Mounted', '/dev/mapper/rootvg-varlv', '10G', '3.8G', '6.3G', '38%', '/var']
d = ['Filesystem', 'Size', 'Used', 'Avail', 'Use%', 'Mounted', '/dev/mapper/appvg-varmwarelv', '20G', '33M', '20G', '1%', '/var/mware']
remove_duplicates = list(set(a+b+c+d))
```

Comment: +1, but I'm curious about the comparison between merging the lists first and then `set`ting them, and `set`ting the lists first and then taking their union...

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess

def disk():
    df_set = set()
    for i in ('/tmp', '/usr/mware', '/var', '/var/mware'):
        df1 = subprocess.Popen(['df','-h', i], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split()
        df1.remove("on")
        df_set = df_set.union(set(df1))
    print(list(df_set))
disk()
```

Above code will merge your list and remove duplicates from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate and use [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) :

```
def disk():
    df = []
    for i in ('/tmp' , '/usr/mware' , '/var' , '/var/mware'):
        df1 = subprocess.Popen(['df','-h', i], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split()
        df1.remove("on")
        df = df + df1
    return set(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

# prepare a list of columns in the beginning
df_out = [['Filesystem', 'Size', 'Used', 'Avail', 'Use%', 'Mounted']]

def disk():
    for i in ('/tmp' , '/usr/mware' , '/var' , '/var/mware'):
        df1 = subprocess.Popen(['df','-h', i], 
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split()
        df1.remove("on")

        # append the remaining columns in the list 'df1'
        df_out.append(df1[6:])

disk()

# print the final output
print df_out
```

This will give you the output as -

```
[['Filesystem', 'Size', 'Used', 'Avail', 'Use%', 'Mounted'],
 ['/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmplv', '2.0G', '39M', '2.0G', '2%', '/tmp'],
 ['/dev/mapper/appvg-usrmwarelv', '20G', '33M', '20G', '1%', '/usr/mware'],
 ['/dev/mapper/rootvg-varlv', '10G', '3.8G', '6.3G', '38%', '/var'],
 ['/dev/mapper/appvg-varmwarelv', '20G', '33M', '20G', '1%', '/var/mware']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`set.union`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.union) method:

```
list(set(df1).union(df2, df3, df4))  # assuming the invidual lists are called df1, df2, ...
```

a `set` is an unordered collection of **unique** objects. You'll lose the duplicates but also lose your order. In case you want it ordered and without duplicates you could use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain

list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(chain(a, b, c, d)))
```